VS Code's problem in identifying NextJS modules in projects where typescript is not used
A strange thing happened to me in VS Code is that when I use the NextJS project with TypeScript, there is no problem, but when I install the NextJS project without TypeScript, it cannot recognize and import the modules. And I'm sure that this problem is only in VS Code because I tried it on Atom and it didn't have any problem
This error after manual import of the module in VS Code.
File name 'c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/node_modules/next/Link.d.ts' differs from already included file name 'c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/node_modules/next/link.d.ts' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Referenced via './link.d.ts' from file 'c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/node_modules/next/index.d.ts'
    Imported via 'next/Link' from file 'c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/app/das/page.jsx' with packageId 'next/Link.d.ts@14.1.4'
    Referenced via './link.d.ts' from file 'c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/node_modules/next/index.d.ts'ts(1149)
index.d.ts(14, 22): File is included via reference here.
index.d.ts(14, 22): File is included via reference here.
module "c:/Users/ali/Desktop/01234/ali/node_modules/next/link"

